# PHP strtotime timezone

Tags: php, timezone, strtotime

i have problem with PHP strtotime converting to different timezone.
My code is simple:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Bratislava");
echo date("H:i",strtotime("20:00 America/New_York")); 
?>
```

This code is returning: **02:00**.
But it should return 14:00.

Can you help me please to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you add "Y m d" to the date? Maybe it reads 20:00 as something else

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This code is returning: 02:00. But it should return 14:00.

No, it's right. You're converting from 8pm in New York (currently UTC-4 due to DST) into the Europe/Bratislava time zone (currently UTC+2 due to DST).

So:

```
New York:   8pm
UTC:        Midnight
Bratislava: 2am
```

If you're trying to convert *from* a Europe/Bratislava time *into* a New York time, then you need to switch your time zone IDs.

Comment: New York is UTC-5 and Bratislava is UTC+1

Comment: @MateiMihai: Not in the summer. DST adds an hour to each of those.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i want to change from BRATISLAVA to NEW YORK, how to do it please?

Comment: @RomanHolic: As I said in the answer, switch your time zone IDs.